# Plot with pandas: group and mean

Tags: python, pandas, plot

My data from my 'combos' data frame looks like this:

```
pr = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,.....1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]

lmi = [200, 200, 200, 250, 250,.....780, 780, 780, 800, 800, 800]

pred = [0.16, 0.18, 0.25, 0.43, 0.54......., 0.20, 0.34, 0.45, 0.66]
```

I plot the results like this:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

for pr in [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]:
    ax.plot(combos[combos.pr==pr].lmi, combos[combos.pr==pr].pred, label=pr)

ax.set_xlabel('lmi')
ax.set_ylabel('pred')
ax.legend(loc='best')
```

And I get this plot:

[image]

How can I plot means of "pred" for each "lmi" data point when keeping the pairs (lmi, pr) intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of your updates to the question it is now clear that you want to calculate the means for each pair `(pr, lmi)`. This can be done by grouping over these columns and then simply calling `mean()`. With `reset_index()`, we then restore the DataFrame format to the previous form.

```
$ combos.groupby(['lmi', 'pr']).mean().reset_index()

   lmi   pr  pred
0  200  1.0  0.16
1  200  2.0  0.18
2  200  3.0  0.25
3  250  1.0  0.54
4  250  4.0  0.43
5  780  2.0  0.20
6  780  3.0  0.34
7  780  4.0  0.45
8  800  1.0  0.66
```

In this new DataFrame `pred` does contain the means and you can use the same plotting procedure you have been using before.

Answer (score 3):

You can first group your `DataFrame` by `lmi` then compute the mean for each group just as your title suggests:

```
combos.groupby('lmi').pred.mean().plot()
```

In one line we:

1. Group the combos `DataFrame` by the `lmi` column
2. Get the `pred` column for each `lmi`
3. Compute the mean across the pred column for each `lmi` group
4. Plot the mean for each `lmi` group